# Why does the answer here use $ \Delta S=Q/T$ even though this isn’t reversible?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, reversibility

[image]

This question for my thermodynamics course ends up using $\Delta S = Q_{\text{waste}} / T,$ but I was taught that $ \Delta S=Q/T$ is only valid if the process is reversible. The question makes it pretty clear it isn’t reversible... for clarity, the correct answers to 4 and 5 are 175 kJ and -225 kJ respectively. Why can I use this formula here?

Comment: Remember that Entropy is a state quantity which only depends on the initial and final parameters of the states. So if you go from state A to state B, that's all the Entropy change cares about. It's your choice whether you want to go reversibly or irreversibly. It won't change anything.

Comment: @Tachyon209 Please post answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Apologies. I thought that this small point wasn't worth putting as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is supposed to apply to a continuous flow process operating at steady state, with the system in contact with a constant temperature reservoir at 298 K.  So, from the first and 2nd laws of thermodynamics applied to this control volume system, $$\dot{q}-\dot{w}=\Delta h$$ and $$\frac{\dot{q}}{T}+\dot{\sigma}=\Delta s$$where $\dot{q}$ is the heat flow per mole from the reservoir to the control volume, $\dot{w}$ is the shaft work per mole done on the surroundings, and $\dot{\sigma}$ is the entropy generated per mole of fluid passing through the control volume.  If we combine these two equations, we obtain
$$\dot{w}=-\Delta h+T\Delta s-T\dot{\sigma}=-\Delta g-T\dot{\sigma}$$

Of course, if this were a closed system, the same equations would apply if $\dot{w}$ were interpreted as the non-PV work.